# Error in (count)/scale : non-numeric argument to binary operator in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a plot using ggplot2 showing the percentage of vote for political parties in a particular  region relative to the number of voters in the region not in  the country.

This is my data frame:

```
   data <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
                 REGION Q99
                 Tunis  Nahdha
                 Tunis Jabha
                 Tunis  NidaaTounes
                 Tunis  Nepasvoter
                Tunis  Nepasvoter
                 Tunis  Nepasvoter
               Tunis  NidaaTounes
                 Tunis  Nepasvoter
                Tunis        Nahdha
               Tunis  NidaaTounes
                 Tunis           CPR
                Tunis        Nahdha
                Tunis        Autres
                Tunis  Nepasvoter
                Tunis  Nepasvoter
                 Tunis        Nahdha
                 Tunis Jabha
               Tunis  Nepasvoter
                Tunis        Nahdha
                Tunis        Nahdha
               Tunis JabhaChaabia
                Tunis        Autres
                Tunis  Nepasvoter
                Tunis  NidaaTounes
                Tunis  Nepasvoter
                Tunis  NidaaTounes
                Tunis  Nepasvoter
                Tunis  NidaaTounes
                Tunis Jabha
                Tunis  NidaaTounes
                Tunis        Autres
                Tunis        Nahdha
                Tunis        Nahdha
                Tunis        Autres
                Tunis Jabha
                Tunis  Nepasvoter
                Tunis  Nepasvoter
               Tunis           CPR
                Tunis        Nahdha
                 Tunis  Nepasvoter
                Tunis  Nepasvoter
                Tunis  Nepasvoter
                Tunis        Nahdha
                 Tunis  NidaaTounes
                 Tunis           CPR
                Tunis           CPR
                 Tunis  Nepasvoter
                Tunis        Autres
                 Tunis        Nahdha
                Tunis  NidaaTounes
                Tunis        Nahdha
                Tunis        Autres
                Tunis  Nepasvoter
              Ariana        Nahdha
               Ariana           CPR
               Ariana        Nahdha
               Ariana  Nepasvoter
               Ariana  NidaaTounes
              Ariana           CPR
               Ariana  Nepasvoter
               Ariana        Nahdha
               Ariana  Nepasvoter
              Ariana  NidaaTounes
               Ariana           CPR
               Ariana  NidaaTounes
               Ariana  NidaaTounes
               Ariana  NidaaTounes
              Ariana           CPR
              Ariana        Nahdha
               Ariana           CPR
              Ariana        Nahdha
              Ariana        Nahdha
               Ariana           CPR
               Ariana        Nahdha
               Ariana  Nepasvoter
               Ariana  NidaaTounes
             Ariana  NidaaTounes
              Ariana        Nahdha      ')
```

First I used this code:

```
  g <- ggplot(data, aes(x = REGION, y =(..count..)/(nrow(data[data$REGION=="Ariana",])), fill = Q99))
  g <- g + geom_bar(position = "stack")
```

But I got this error:

> Error in nrow(data[data$REGION == "Ariana", ]) : object 'data' not found

then I tried to use `environment= environment()`

```
  scale = nrow(data[data$REGION=="Ariana",])
  g <- ggplot(data, aes(x = REGION, y = (..count..)/scale, fill = Q99), environment = environment())
  g <- g + geom_bar(position = "stack")
```

then I got this error:

> Error in (count)/scale : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @kaksat I add the data frame

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I have completely grasped what are you trying to do. Anyway I would avoid any computation in the plotting code. Prepare the data first.
This is my solution if this is what are you trying to achieve:

```
   dataSummarized <- group_by(data, REGION, Q99) %>% 
            summarise(percentVotes = n()) %>% 
            mutate(freq = percentVotes / sum(percentVotes))



    g <- ggplot(dataSummarized, aes(x = REGION, y = freq, fill = Q99))
    g <- g + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
    g
```